# How can I safely resolve homebrew and zsh's conflicting needs for /usr/local/share/zsh ownership?

Tags: macos, homebrew, zsh, file-permissions

After switching my shell from `bash` to `zsh` with the macOS Catalina update, Homebrew and zsh are fighting over how they need `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions` and `/usr/local/share/zsh` to be owned.

zsh prefers that `/usr/local/share/zsh/**/*` be owned by `root`, and otherwise raises the annoying error

```
zsh compinit: insecure directories and files, run compaudit for list.
Ignore insecure directories and files and continue [y] or abort compinit [n]?
```

every time I log in as root, for example via `sudo -s`.

I ran `compaudit` as root then `chown root`'d and `chmod g-w`'d all the directories that it listed. That satisfied `zsh` but now `homebrew` isn't happy.

Any `brew` `install` or `upgrade` fails with

```
Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/zsh
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

You should change the ownership of these directories to your user.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions

And make sure that your user has write permission.
  chmod u+w /usr/local/share/zsh /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

`brew doctor` gives the same message as a warning.

Is there a compromise between the two? Or one of these warnings I can safely suppress? If so, how?

Comment: I've created a [discussion topic on the Homebrew Discourse](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-can-i-safely-resolve-homebrew-and-zshs-conflicting-needs-for-usr-local-share-zsh-ownership/6082) for this question.

Answer (score 5):

I just made the message does not come up by adding the following line in my `.zshrc` file.

```
ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true"
```

If it does not work, try to add the line on the first line of the `.zshrc` file.

Comment: What exactly does disabling `COMPFIX` _do_? I'm having trouble finding documentation.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/compfix.zsh) is the source code for `COMPFIX`. It flags insecure directories.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /usr/local/share/zsh/
```

next

```
chmod go-w site-functions
```

Comment: but I need it to be group-writeable :/

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation, I recommend the following:

```
brew update 
brew upgrade 
brew doctor
```

The last one might mention exactly what you need to do, in my case it was a simple solution

```
brew cleanup
```

This removed the old conflicting symlink I was showing prior:

`compinit:503: no such file or directory: /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew_cask`

However if you want to see what would be cleaned up prior to actually cleaning up you can:

```
brew cleanup -n
brew cleanup --dry-run
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `compinit` call somewhere like in your .zshrc. Change it to `compinit -u` which will silence the warning.

/usr/share/zsh/5.7.1/functions/compinit is responsible for that warning (change 5.7.1 to match your zsh version)

Comment: Indeed that does work _after_ I am logged in as root. Running `compinit` triggers the error while `compinit -u` bypasses it. However adding the `-u` flag to the `compinit` call in my `.zshrc` does not work—I still get the warning when I run `sudo -s`.

Comment: There is other place where compinit is called then. .zshrc for root or system wide config for example.